# Passing values to an URL in SSRS and opening the URL in a new window

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to use the following to open a new window while passing some values to the url. I'm new at this so I'm guessing it's something minor.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('https://website.com/Move/Closeout.aspx?cusid=" & Fields!CustomerID.Value & "&soid=" & Fields!SalesorderID.Value', '_blank'))"
```

In the report, the link doesn't even appear as a link and when I click on it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the url as a navigation link. So your field expression will simply be `Fields!CustomerID.Value` then right-click the cell, select `Text Box Properties...` then `Action`. Select the `Go to URL` radiobutton and enter your javascript expression in there:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('https://website.com/Move/Closeout.aspx?cusid=" & Fields!CustomerID.Value & "&soid=" & Fields!SalesorderID.Value', '_blank'))"
```

This will turn the displayed CustomerID in the cell into a clickable link.

I also change the `Font`.`Color` to `Blue` to indicate it is a link.